# How can I add custom value to json array in response in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a json array `[ {"name": "abc"}, {"name": "mno" } , {"name":"xyz"} ]`. I returned this from ruby on rails. but want to add one more message value in the response such that, json data being returned would be like below , a mesage with a value and then the array.

```
"message" : "somevalue" 

[ {"name": "abc"}, {"name": "mno" } , {"name":"xyz"} ]
```

in the controller , I have `return statement => render json : respone //this is a json array response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```rb
render json: {"message": "somevalue", "response": response}
```

Simple as that, should do the trick.

By the way, you can also call the "response" field whatever you want. It's gonna be the key of the object you get in JSON later.

Comment: thanks for the comment.

Comment: Did it work? Btw I would also recommend adding a `status: 200` or some other code after every request. If you are not familiar with status codes you should read more about them...very useful.

Comment: yes that worked , but I'm still trying to see if i can make it better. I want to come with a function, which I can use to edit the data before I send it back to the client. do you have any suggestions around this?

Comment: This can easily be done with serializers. As I can see, you are using API only Rails so I can recommend you Active Model Serializers gem to tweak the data you want to send back for each model. Here is the link to gem's GitHub: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Btw can you also put this answer as Accpeted so other people can see that this is the correct solution. Thanks! Don't hesitate to ask any more question

Comment: if there are any samples on how to use this gem pass it along. I just marked the a solution. I have been going through a tutorial to learn bascis of the ruby. SO wouldn't let me open a new question , as apparently I have already open too many questions.

Comment: You could read through the documentation but this article looks much easier to understand, check it out https://learn.co/lessons/using-active-model-serializer